# Running latex2html with miktex on Windows

Tags: windows, html, latex, miktex

I have installed miktex on a Windows machine. I would like to run latex2html, and have installed it with the miktex package manager. However, after that, I do not know hot to run latex2html and have not been able to find any info about it. I cannot locate any file called latex2html.exe/bat or the like.

Where do I find latex2html, or how do I run it?

Comment: How did you install `latex2html` from MikTeX? I searched the packages and there is no such a package! 

Comment: @Foad I have not used it for the last 6+ years. I don't recall actually. I tried miktex on my mac and it does not include latex2html. Maybe you can find guidance on latex2html installation here: https://www.latex2html.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX2HTML):

> LaTeX2HTML is a converter written in
>   Perl that converts LaTeX documents to
>   HTML.

So I suppose you will need to install [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) first.